# How do I point server1.example.com server2.example.com etc... to different servers?

Tags: vps, centos5

I have example.com with host #1,
I also have two different servers with two different IP's on host#2. I need server1.example.com to point to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 and server2.example.com to point to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify DNS so that the A record for `server1.example.com` points to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1, and the A record for `server2.example.com` points to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2.

Comment: Would I do this via the VPS's or my registrar's domain manager?

Comment: It depends on which one is authoritative for that domain.  You can find out which one it is with `dig example.com NS`.